# track the value o textbox

Tags: jquery

Hi i have a textbox that is hidden.

And i chenge the value based on clicks inside the page.

I want to track somehow the value so when value is 0 to call a ajax.

i tried using .change but is not working

Does anyone have an idea

Comment: Is this a hidden input, or a hidden textbox?

Can you post some code?

Comment: Why don't you hook up the event of the clicks to make an ajax call and ignore the textbox? Btw, if it's hidden, why not use a hidden input type?

Comment: This is a hidden input counting the number of files for upload

Comment: Can you post the html for your input and your jQuery code. From what your describing, I suspect its not all that big.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook up the click events that are changing the hidden field's value. In the handler for those events, call a function that checks the hidden value and call your Ajax function if it's 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#something").click(function(){
 // do something
 if($("#yourTextBox").val()==="0"){
 //do your ajax
 }
}
```